# Let f(x) be polynomial with integer coefficients and root $c$. Show that $c$ divides the constant term.

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

Let $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$ be polynomial whose coefficients are integers and whose leading coefficient is $1$. If $c$ is integer and root of $f$, show that $c$ divides $a_0$.

(From : Serge Lang - Basic Mathematics, Exercise 5, page 328)

What I tried:

---

If $c$ is root then:
 $f(c)=0$ it follows that,
 $f(c)=c^n+a_{n-1}c^{n-1}+...+c+a_0$
 $0-a_0=c(c^{n-1}+a_{n-1}c^{n-2}+...+1)$

Let $S=(c^{n-1}+a_{n-1}c^{n-2}+...+1)$
We know that $c$ and the coefficients $a_{n-1},a_{n-2},...,a_0$ are integers, hence S will also be an integer.

It follows that,
 $-a_0=cS$

Hence, $c$ divides $a_0$.

---

Is there a mistake?

Supposing that I didn't made a mistake, it will be the same even if the leading coefficient is not $1$. Is that right?

Comment: That looks good to me.

Comment: It's quite fine. In the same way, you can prove the full *rational roots theorem* : if a rational number $a/b$  (in irreducible form) is a root, then the numerator divides the constant term, and the denominator divides the leading coefficient.

Comment: @Bernard If we consider the _rational roots theorem_, do we have a special case when the leading coefficient is 1? Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: You can also look at Vieta's formula for the polynomial. What would be $a_0$ in terms of the roots of the polynomial and / or the independent terms of the factorization?

Comment: Well, it yields in this case a rational root must be an integer.

Comment: I see, it follows from the proof of the _rational roots theorem_ that when the leading coefficient is 1 the roots are integers.  
I'll also check the Vieta's formula.